# Implementing OpenFlow enabled Wifi network in NS-3

Tags: c++, wifi, ns-3, openflow

I'm currently using NS-3 network simulator to implement a Wifi network 802.11b which uses OpenFlow.
I'm trying to link my nodes and my switch devices. As shown in the openflow-switch.cc file this is done as follows with csma:

```
 // Create the csma links, from each terminal to the switch

NetDeviceContainer terminalDevices;
NetDeviceContainer switchDevices;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  NetDeviceContainer link = csma.Install (NodeContainer (terminals.Get(i), csmaSwitch));
  terminalDevices.Add (link.Get (0));
  switchDevices.Add (link.Get (1));
}
```

I am using the WifiHelper wifi for my script but cannot as simply use:

```
 NetDeviceContainer link = wifi.Install(NodeContainer (staDevices.Get (i), Switch));
```

Because the wifi.Install method requires parameters:

```
wifi.Install (phy, mac, wifiStaNodes);
```

I've tried to pass in the nodes like so:

```
NetDeviceContainer link = wifi.Install(phy, mac, (NodeContainer (wifiStaNodes.Get (i), Switch)));

terminals.Add (link.Get(2));
switchDevices.Add (link.Get(3));
```

But when running the script I received a 'terminated with signal SIGSEGV' Error and on debugging was given no further information as to why the error was being returned.

Is there any suggestions as to how to overcome this issue as I've tried various ways of creating the link but none have worked.
Appreciate any suggestions,
Sean